# Username and password within files

Tags: c++, file, passwords, fstream

This has probably been answered somewhere, but I spent a few minutes looking and counldn't find anything. So I have two files, `User.txt` and `Pass.txt`.

`Pass.txt` looks like this:

```
password
test
```

`User.txt` looks like this:

```
username
test
```

This is my code here:

```
        cout << "Username: " << endl; //input user
        cin >> user;
        cout << "Password: " << endl; //input pass
        cin >> pass;
        userfile.open("User.txt");
        passfile.open("Pass.txt");
        while (getline(userfile, STRINGT) && getline(passfile, STRINGO))
        {
            if (user == STRINGT.c_str() && pass == STRINGO.c_str()) //if user and pass are both in file
            {
                //i had a break here, (its in a switch) so i replaced it with a cout, but it didn't change
            }
        }
        cout << "Incorrect username or password" << endl;
        _getch(); //pause
        return 0; //end program
```

Whenever I run, it says it's incorrect everytime. I am checking all the caps and whatnot, can't figure out problem.

I have all the other nessesary fstream file stuff already declared above

Thanks in advance C:

Comment: the break just breaks the while loop not switch

Comment: thats what I thought, so I got rid of it, but it still doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need:

```
    bool found = false;

    while (getline(userfile, STRINGT) && getline(passfile, STRINGO))
    {
        if (strcmp(user, STRINGT.c_str()) == 0 && strcmp(pass, STRINGO.c_str()) == 0) //if user and pass are both in file
        {
            found = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (!found) {
        cout << "Incorrect username or password" << endl;
    }
```